# I receive nothing in recvfrom from Socket Python

Tags: python, sockets, udp

In one moment of code, recvfrom is working, but in another part of code, isn't. That's my code:

```
try:
    s.bind(('', 10555))
    a.bind(('', 25465))
    data, add = a.recvfrom(1024) #at this moment, all it's fine
    print(data.decode())
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    sys.exit()
while True:
    print('Esperando...')
    data, address = a.recvfrom(1024) #but here, nothing is receive
    print('Recebido: {}\nRepassando...'.format(
        data.decode()))
```

I really don't know why isn't working, so... Help pls...
I'm using Python 3.5.3

Comment: Who is sending the data?

Comment: This socket server is running in a Debian Server and I'm sending from my PC in another ip

Comment: Is your payload larger than 1024 bytes? Unless you have to flush or thing like that.

Comment: how can I see this?

Comment: I have not enough information to help you. When you deal with client/server and don't know how both sides are working together it's like trying to understand a conversation over a telephone when you only hear one side.